# Modify Metadata during Grpc Bidirectional Streaming in C++

Tags: c++, grpc, bidi

Using Async bidirectional streaming, can i create a client stream (ClientAsyncReaderWriter) and modify metadata value in ClientContext for each request sent on that stream? Also, on the server side, can i use the ServerContext of the incoming client stream, to send modified metadata value for each response sent back to the client on the bidiriectional stream. Please let me know if there is a way to do this since i dont want to maintain multiple streams for each of the metadata value. I would like to use same stream and send different metadata value for a key for each request/response exchanged on that bidirectional stream.

Answer (score 0):

This is intentionally not supported.

Metadata is intended to be at the RPC layer per bidi stream; not per req/response.  If you wish to communicate information per req/response, you should put that inside the req/response.

Metadata is intended to be for all req/response in the same stream.

Comment: Hi donnadionne, thanks for the response. My requirement was to inject some information like a cookie in each request/response within the stream, so that envoy proxy inside a service mesh can use that cookie to hash and load balance the request/responses. So, you mean in this case, i will need to have separate streams per cookie so that the load balancing works per stream and not per request/response within that stream.??

Answer (score 0):

Metadata is tied to stream; please see documentation https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/CONCEPTS.md#abstract-grpc-protocol

There is the client interceptor 
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/client_interceptor.h
which may be able to help

These tests show examples how the interceptors can be used:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/test/cpp/end2end/client_interceptors_end2end_test.cc

Comment: Hi @donnadionne, I check the interceptor functions. I am not sure if, for a bidi streaming async grpc, i can add an http2 header information per Write call on the asynchronous stream by intercepting PRE_SEND_MESSAGE??